# Vertical scrollbar in FLET app, does not appear

Tags: python, flet

I am building a FLET app, but sometimes I have a datatable which is too large for the frame it is in. For the row I have a scrollbar appearing, but for the column I just don't seem to get it working.

In this code a scrollbar simply does not appear.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.max_columns = 100
from services.bag import PCHN
from utils.convertors import dataframe_to_datatable
import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.page):
    def bag_service(e):
        pc = '9351BP' if postal_code_field.value == '' else postal_code_field.value
        hn = '1' if house_number_field.value == '' else house_number_field.value
        address = PCHN(pc, 
                       hn).result
        bag_container[0] = dataframe_to_datatable(address)
        page.update() # This is not updating my bag_table in place though. It stays static as it is.

    # define form fields
    postal_code_field = ft.TextField(label='Postal code')
    house_number_field = ft.TextField(label='House number')
    submit_button = ft.ElevatedButton(text='Submit', on_click=bag_service)

    # fields for the right column
    address = PCHN('9351BP', '1').result
    bag_table = dataframe_to_datatable(address)
    bag_container = [bag_table]
    
    # design layout
    # 1 column to the left as a frame and one to the right with two rows
    horizontal_divider = ft.Row
    left_column = ft.Column
    right_column = ft.Column
    
    # fill the design
    page.add(
        horizontal_divider(
        [left_column(
            [postal_code_field,
                 house_number_field,
                 submit_button
                 ]
            ),
         right_column(
             [
                 ft.Container(
                        ft.Row(
                            bag_container, 
                            scroll='always'
                            ),
                        bgcolor=ft.colors.BLACK,
                        width=800,)
                ],scroll='always'
             )
        ]
        )
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ft.app(target=main,
           view=ft.WEB_BROWSER,
           port=666
           )
```

I am lost as to what could be the case here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to scroll a `Column`, you must set a fixed `height` on the `Column` or set `expand=True` on the Column and all parents. Otherwise the column will grow to fit all its children.

#### Example:

```py
import flet as ft


def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.add(
        ft.Column(
            scroll=ft.ScrollMode.ALWAYS,
            expand=True, # first alternative
            # height=page.height, # second alternative (without expand=True)
            controls=[
                ft.ListTile(
                    title=ft.Text(value=str(i)),
                )
                for i in range(20)
            ],
        ),
    )


ft.app(target=main)
```

#### Why does `expand` help?

Flet's `expand` is the equivalent to wrapping a widget by an `Expanded` or `Flexible` widget in Flutter, setting the size of a control/widget to it's maximum (or a specified value) within its parent.
Without `expand`, the view, which acts like just another Column, grows as large as the child Column wants to be. Setting `expand` restricts and expands the child Column to the parent's size. Only then does a scrollbar make sense.